# Blazor highlight selected table row

Tags: css, .net-core, razor, html-table, blazor

I have the following table rendering in my blazor project:

```
<table class="table table-bordered accountTable @HighlightSelected" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if (Accounts != null) 
    {
        @foreach (var account in Accounts)
        {
            <tr @onclick="@(() => ReturnRowData(account))"> 
                <td >@account.Id</td>
                <td >@account.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <p>No accounts to display...</p>
    }

    </tbody>
</table>

@code{
  [Parameter]
    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Account> OnRowClicked{get;set;}
    public string HighlightSelected = "normal";
public async void ReturnRowData(Account account)
{
    HighlightSelected = "highlight";
    await OnRowClicked.InvokeAsync(account);
}
}
```

When a row on this table is clicked, it is returning the selected rows data back to my index page for use in other functions. What I'm trying to do here is add a new background colour to the selected row.

The parameter on the table `@HighlightSelected` is a string variable which I am using to substitute in my desired `CSS` change. However, the css change is added to every single row instead of just the single selected.

In my css I have tried different combinations of targeting the specific td I want, but it always results in the whole table being highlighted. Example as

```
.highlight table tbody tr.highlight td {
    background-color: red;
}
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

I'm aware that this can be done with `javascript` but I would like to avoid that at all costs if at all possible.

Comment: To start with your applying the class to the whole table. You need to have some sort of state variable for each account and apply the class to the row based on state. You will also need to use `@key` on the row.

Comment: So long as he doesn't need to be able to multi-select, then a single comparison item will be fine.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 he talks about "selected rows"

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too.  However, I also saw the several uses of "row" without an "s," and the word "single."

Answer (score 6):

Whenever I'm using a List, I often create an individual instance for selection and comparison.

```
@page "/accounts"


<table class="table table-bordered accountTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (AccountsList != null)
        {
            @foreach (var account in AccountsList)
            {
                string colorClass= (account == SelectedAccount) ? "MyHighlightClass" : "";
                <tr class="@colorClass" style="color:navy; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline" @onclick="() => { ReturnRowData(account); SelectedAccount = account; }">
                    <td>@account.Id</td>
                    <td>@account.Name</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No accounts to display...</p>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
@if (SelectedAccount.Id != 0)
{
    <h3>Selected account #@SelectedAccount.Id (@SelectedAccount.Name) </h3>
}

@code {
    public class Account
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name = "";
    }
    [Parameter]
    public List<Account> AccountsList { get; set; } = new List<Account>() {
            new Account(){ Id = 1, Name="John" },
            new Account(){ Id = 2, Name="Jeff" },
            new Account(){ Id = 3, Name="Jane" }
     };
    Account SelectedAccount { get; set; } = new Account();

    void ReturnRowData(Account account)
    {
        // Do data stuff.
    }
}
```